# 買えっつてだろうが　meaning

Tags: meaning

> いつもいつも計算して買えっつてだろうが。

It's very colloquial but I can't understand this part 買えっつてだろうが。
Why is written like this 買えっつて ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it's meant to say 計算して買えっつってっだろうが (「計算して買え」って言ってるだろうが).
っつってっだろう＜っつってるだろう＜って言ってるだろう